# Backup MBR , boot loaders etc for trouble free OS installing/uninstalling?

Tags: boot, operating-systems, bootloader

First I installed xp , then xp64 , then windows 8 developer preview , now I wish to install a linux flavor. This is all easy.

Some months later I may want to uninstall windows 8 preview and install its beta. OR I may want to remove linux without reinstalling windows. Now the problem with MBR and bootloaders begins. In my experience , sometimes here something  goes wrong at this point and I end up in an unbootable state.

Is there a way to 'manage' all bootloaders(second stage)/MBR , so that they can be simply restored to a particular state after a OS is removed/added? I know MBR can be backed up easy(dd command,hirens boot cd), but that doesn't seem to be enough..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Start with this GHacks How to:

- [How To Backup And Restore The MBR In Windows](http://www.ghacks.net/2010/09/01/how-to-backup-and-restore-the-mbr-in-windows/)